# Get browser to re-evaluate a changed DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML:

```
<div>AAAAA</div>
<div id="bbb"></div>
<fish></fish>
```

And JS/jQuery:

```
$('#bbb').replaceWith('<div>BBBB</div>');
$('fish')[0].replaceWith('<div>CCCC</div>');
```

What gets displayed (on Chrome) is:

```
AAAAA
BBBB
<div>CCCC</div>
```

It appears that once the browser marks an element bad, it won't re-evaluate it when it's changed.  How can I make it display:

```
AAAAA
BBBB
CCCC
```

I can't figure out how to do it.  Any help would sure be appreciated.

Thanks.

Blake McBride

Comment: Once you fix the mistake of using `[0]` on the second line of js it outputs what you are wanting: https://jsfiddle.net/4s8wfuzm/

Comment: "once the browser marks an element bad" <-- no clue what that means

Comment: I presumed when the browser saw <fish> it ignores it, or marks it bad. I was incorrectly assuming that the browser was "marking" it bad and refusing to evaluate it further.  I was wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Patrick.  It works now!

Answer (score 2):

Custom dom elements/components do not have full browser support yet, you may check [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=custom-elements).

My advice would be to use `div`'s with css classes or id's. Otherwise, you cannot really do much without using a reactive framework from the entire forest of frameworks there is, as they would allow you to define those custom elements and perform actions with them.

Comment: Once you make the change suggested by Patrick, it works in Chrome and Firefox.  I think the custom components you are referring to are something different.  I am basically doing a search and replace.  The browser ends up only seeing the new code.